# w.fn.init mistake when trying to read data from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to console log a data that will be later sent to the server:

1. An array of numbers;
2. Number of draws;

Everything is working with an array, but when I'm trying to console.log draws, the following message shows `w.fn.init [input.draw-number, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]`

**Here is the HTML I want to get data from:**

```
             <tr>
                <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
                <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
                <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
                <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
                <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
                <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
                <td><input class="draw-number" type="number" maxlength="6"></td>
                <td><button id="button-send_results" type = "submit">Let's win!</button></td>
            </tr>
```

**My index.js:**

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#button-send_results').click(() => {
    const userNumbersArray = [];
    const drawNumber = $('.draw-number');
    $('.lottery-number').each(function () {
      userNumbersArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log(userNumbersArray);
    console.log(drawNumber);
  });

});
```

Comment: You need to add `.val()` to show the value like `console.log(drawNumber.val());`

Comment: can I assign the value of this field to my `drawnumber` variable? 
Like this `const drawNumber = $('.draw-number').val();`

Comment: Yes sure you can, check my updated answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.val()` to get the value of the input instead of the input DOM element, like :

```
const drawNumber = $('.draw-number').val();
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#button-send_results').click(() => {
    const userNumbersArray = [];
    const drawNumber = $('.draw-number').val();

    $('.lottery-number').each(function() {
      userNumbersArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log(userNumbersArray);
    console.log(drawNumber);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
  <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
  <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
  <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
  <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
  <td><input class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2"></td>
  <td><input class="draw-number" type="number" maxlength="6" placeholder="draw-number"></td>
  <td><button id="button-send_results" type="submit">Let's win!</button></td>
</tr>
```